# Select * from table where = "string with linebreaks"

Tags: java, string, select

I'm working with Java and MySQL and I have to select from the DB something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT type FROM test_case where input=" + inputTestCase;
```

The problem is that inputTestCase string sometimes has linebreaks.
In these cases I get an exception, for example:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near '5
8
10' at line 2
```

where:

```
'5
8
10'
```

is my `inputTestCase` .

What should I do to make the `Select` to work. Thank you all for the help!

P.S: I don't initializate `inputTestCase` . The value of this string comes from the DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using JDBC, always, *always* use a `PreparedStatement` when including dynamic data in a query.  If you don't, you are highly vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, where a malicious user could execute arbitrary SQL commands on your database.

As a bonus to this, using `PreparedStatement` will escape your input for you, so you don't have to worry about sanitizing it like in this case.

For more information, take a look at the Java Tutorial - [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).